# How do I give this permission to run? New to mac os

Tags: ios, nativescript

I "git cloned" my project onto the MacBook Pro. the run ios command seems to fail because of permissions.  What do I need to set?  I'm brand new to MacOs and have no clue how to proceed.

These are the settings on the folder in question:

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 jbaird  staff    170 Sep  5 11:05 NativeScript.framework
-rw-r--r--  1 jbaird  staff    135 Sep  5 11:05 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  4 jbaird  staff    136 Sep  5 11:05 TKLiveSync
-rw-r--r--  1 jbaird  staff  11433 Sep  5 11:05 TNSDebugging.h
-rw-r--r--  1 jbaird  staff   2871 Sep  5 11:05 TNSExceptionHandler.h
-rw-r--r--  1 jbaird  staff   1187 Sep  5 11:05 main.m
drwxr-xr-x  4 jbaird  staff    136 Sep  5 11:05 metadata-generator
-rw-r--r--  1 jbaird  staff   1590 Sep  5 11:05 nativescript-build.xcconfig
-rw-r--r--  1 jbaird  staff    421 Sep  5 11:05 nativescript-post-build
-rw-r--r--  1 jbaird  staff    117 Sep  5 11:05 nativescript-pre-build
-rw-r--r--  1 jbaird  staff     26 Sep  5 11:05 nativescript-pre-link
-rw-r--r--  1 jbaird  staff   2293 Sep  5 11:05 strip-dynamic-framework-architectures.sh
```

And the error message:

```
new-host:nativescript jbaird$ tns run ios
Searching for devices...
Executing before-liveSync hook 
Project successfully created.
Executing before-prepare hook from /Users/jbaird/Documents/development/gr8dates/Nativescript/hooks/before-prepare/nativescript-dev-typescript.js
Found peer TypeScript 2.4.2
Preparing project...
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-angular for ios.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-theme-core for ios.
Successfully prepared plugin tns-core-modules for ios.
Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-intl for ios.
Successfully prepared plugin tns-core-modules-widgets for ios.
Project successfully prepared (iOS)
Building project...
Build settings from command line:

...
-c /Users/jbaird/Documents/development/gr8dates/Nativescript/platforms/ios/build/Nativescript.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Nativescript.build/Script-C97FD7AC1ADE5369004DB2A4.sh
/Users/jbaird/Documents/development/gr8dates/Nativescript/platforms/ios/build/Nativescript.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Nativescript.build/Script-C97FD7AC1ADE5369004DB2A4.sh: line 2: /Users/jbaird/Documents/development/gr8dates/Nativescript/platforms/ios/internal/nativescript-pre-build: Permission denied

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution NativeScript\ PreBuild build/Nativescript.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Nativescript.build/Script-C97FD7AC1ADE5369004DB2A4.sh
(1 failure)
Unable to apply changes on device: C204F45C-A9B4-4412-95BB-A4B7BC077253. Error is: Command xcodebuild failed with exit code 65.
Executing after-watch hook from /Users/jbaird/Documents/development/gr8dates/Nativescript/hooks/after-watch/nativescript-dev-typescript.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and running this command fixed it:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwx platforms/ios/
```

Comment: Doing the same on the android directory fixed my other problem.  So answer that question and I'll mark it the answer.